Proof that the initial uniformity induced by totally bounded spaces is totally bounded
Bourbaki proves this claim in General Topology, chapter II, §4.2, Proposition 3, using the Hausdorff completion. It is however possible to give an "elementary" proof in the case of products (see here), but the proof explicitly uses the Cartesian product structure. Is there a similarly elementary proof in the general case of initial uniformities?

The proof below doesn't make any of use of compactness-related concepts or of the corresponding result for products, and it mostly only assumes to be known the construction of the initial uniformity which Bourbaki presents in General Topology, chap. II, § 2, no. 3, prop. 4.


Let $X$ be a set, let $(Y_\iota)_{\iota\in I}$ be a family of uniform spaces. For every $\iota\in I$, let $f_\iota$ be a mapping from $X$ to $Y_\iota$ such that $f_\iota(X)$ is totally bounded and endow $X$ with the initial uniformity with respect to the mappings $f_\iota$. Then, $X$ is totally bounded.

Proof. Let $U$ be an entourage of $X$. The goal will be to prove the existence of a finite cover of $X$ consisting of $U$-small sets, i.e. sets $K$ such that the relations $x\in K$ and $y\in K$ imply $(x,y)\in U$.
The construction of the initial uniformity presented by Bourbaki yieds the existence of a finite subset $J$ of $I$ such that for every $\iota\in J$ can be chosen an entourage $V_\iota$ of $Y_\iota$ in such a way that
$$\bigcap_{\iota\in J}(f_\iota\times f_\iota)^{-1}(V_\iota)\subset U.$$
For every $\iota\in J$, since $f_\iota(X)$ is totally bounded, there is a finite cover $\mathfrak R_\iota$ of $f_\iota(X)$ consisting of $V_\iota$-small sets. The set
$$\mathfrak R=\left\lbrace\prod_{\iota\in J}A_\iota~\Bigg|~(A_\iota)_{\iota\in J}\in\prod_{\iota\in J}\mathfrak R_\iota\right\rbrace$$
is then a finite cover of $(f_\iota)_{\iota\in J}(X)$, which implies that the set $\lbrace((f_\iota)_{\iota\in J})^{-1}(A)~|~A\in\mathfrak R\rbrace$ is a finite cover of $X$. To conclude the proof, it suffices to show that each set $((f_\iota)_{\iota\in J})^{-1}(A)$ is $U$-small.
Let $A\in\mathfrak R$ and let $x$ and $y$ be two points of $((f_\iota)_{\iota\in J})^{-1}(A)$. For every $\iota\in J$, since the projection $A_\iota$ of $A$ onto $Y_\iota$ is $V_\iota$-small by the definitions of $\mathfrak R$ and $\mathfrak R_\iota$ and since $f_\iota(x)\in A_\iota$ and $f_\iota(y)\in A_\iota$, it follows that $(f_\iota(x),f_\iota(y))\in V_\iota$, which is equivalent to $(x,y)\in (f_\iota\times f_\iota)^{-1}(V_\iota)$. This being true for every $\iota\in J$, it implies
$$(x,y)\in\bigcap_{\iota\in J}(f_\iota\times f_\iota)^{-1}(V_\iota)\subset U$$
as wanted.
